# Where are the Silean Nebula and Hades Nexus?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This nebula has been identified on side quests (I put all priority missions on standby ... ironically) so that I don't miss out on any content.  Is this a case of a galaxy just not being available until the main plot line catches up?

How far do I have to progress to open these up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [two](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Silean_Nebula) IGN [articles](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Hades_Nexus) on them say that you gain access to them after the [Priority: Thessia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Priority:_Thessia) mission near the end of the game, so yes it looks like you need to progress through the main plot line to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Priority Rannoch, I know this from personal experience

Comment: you mean by prioritizing the Rannoch mission because after it The galaxy will be available?

Answer (score 0):

The Cyone system within the Silean Nebula is available fairly early in the game. But there are systems within the Silean Nebula (Phontes and Teyolia -- maybe others) that do not become available until after Priority: Rannoch. I've just completed Priority: Rannoch and Hades Nexus is not yet showing on up the Galaxy Map.

Answer (score 0):

Full Silean Nebula is available after [Priority: Rannoch](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Priority:_Rannoch), while Hades Nexus seems to be after [Priority: Thesia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Priority:_Thessia)

Comment: Please actually quote some information from those links, don't just post links.